# How to prove that a hamiltonian graph must be 2 connected?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm under the assumption that the  starting point of a graph is not sufficient for it to be visited so that means that a circuit would be required, thus it would need to be 2 connected, correct?

Comment: Please see: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=mpgu6wgnZgYC&pg=PA125&dq=proving+a+hamiltonian+graph+must+be+2+connected&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjx4OyouTQAhUDmpQKHQSxAhoQ6AEIGTAA#v=onepage&q=proving%20a%20hamiltonian%20graph%20must%20be%202%20connected&f=false

Comment: Do you know how to prove that a cycle graph $C_n$ is $2$-connected? And that a $2$-connected graph remains $2$-connected if you add more edges to it?